# Speed up random sort and delete (rm) for multiple directories

Tags: rm, optimization

Running MacOS in a terminal which is essentially BSD, hence posting my question here instead of askdifferent. I want to trim my image dataset down in subsequent steps, by deleting files randomly. Some directories have over a 1 million jpgs. My data is in master directory with subdirectories that is only a maxdepth of 1:

```
-master
     -data1
       image.jpgs
     -data2
       image.jpgs
     -data3
       image.jpgs
     -data4
       image.jpgs
... and so forth
```

I found this link:

https://superuser.com/questions/1186350/delete-all-but-1000-random-files-in-a-directory

... and came up with:

```
for f in *.jpg; do find "$f" -type f -print0 | sort -R | tail -n +50001 | xargs -0 rm; done
```

While it does work, I'd like for it to do this recursively for subdirectories, so I don't have to manually do it for every directory. So my questions/requests are:

1. Can I optimize this somehow to speed it up?
2. Will sort/tail return an error when it encounters a directory with fewer than 50,000 files?

Comment: Does that really work? If I read the loop correctly, you're taking each jpg file, running `find` on that file, which should just output that file (and nothing else), running `sort -R` on it (which has no effect since it's just one line), followed by tail, which has no output for the same reason, and running `xargs rm` on no output at all, so nothing gets deleted.

Comment: Crap, you're right. I assumed it was working because "something"  was happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having checked the linked source post, it looks like your loop should actually be:

```
for d in */; do find "$d" -iname '*.jpg' -type f -print0 | sort -zR | tail -zn +50001 | xargs -0r rm; done
```

To be run from the `master` directory.

The `-z` options for `sort` and `tail` are necessary, since the input is null-delimited. Neither will complain if there are fewer than 50000 lines - `sort` doesn't care and `tail` won't output anything, since there is nothing after the 50000th line. `rm` might complain about being run with no arguments, but the `-r` option to GNU `xargs` will prevent it from running `rm` if it gets no input (BSD xargs doesn't need it, but probably won't complain).

Lastly, but most importantly, the `-z` option for null-delimited input probably won't be supported by BSD  tail. You'd need the GNU tail, which can be installed using homebrew.

You probably could do without null-delimited lines, if your filenames are guaranteed not to have spaces, newlines, quotes, backslashes, etc. in them. In that case:

```
for d in */; do find "$d" -type f | sort -R | tail -n +50001 | xargs rm; done
```

Comment: I'm guessing the same is true for head?

Comment: Going by the FreeBSD manpage for head, yes

Comment: The `xargs -r` behaviour is the default on macOS and FreeBSD, but not on e.g. OpenBSD. macOS `xargs` additionally does not have `-r` and will complain if you use it. OpenBSD `xargs` has `-r`.  We really need to stop lumping the BSDs together... :-/